# Factory service calls $http service automatically

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to work on SPA and have declared a factory like this

```
// configure the PersonalDetails service
app.factory("PDService", function ($http) {
    var thisPDService = {};
    // get the data from database
    thisPDService.Get = function () {
        var promise = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/PersonalDetails'
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            },
            function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        return promise;
    };
    return thisPDService;
});
```

My controller looks like this

```
app.controller("PDController", function ($scope, PDService) {
    $scope.Title = "Personal Details List";

    $scope.GetMyData = PDService.Get().then(function (d) {        
            $scope.PersonalDetails = d;
        });
});
```

and view is

```
<table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Active</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="d in PersonalDetails">
        <td>{{d.FirstName}}</td><td>{{d.LastName}}</td><td>{{d.Age}}</td><td>{{d.Active}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

All works great but the problem is when I navigate to this view, it automatically calls the Get() method of the PDService that loads the data in the table. I do not want to do that.

Even if I declare another method in the factory, that method also gets called automatically.

Any help will much appreciated.

Comment: get your $scope.GetMyData in your ctrl into a function and call it whenever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change the controller like this.

```
$scope.GetMyData = function() {

    PDService.Get().then(function (d) {        
                $scope.PersonalDetails = d;
            });
    };
```

and when you need to fill the data, just call **GetMyData**

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I got this.

Comment: Hello Sheo, if it solved your problem, please mark it as the answer please. 
good Luck. ;)

Comment: I did Nadeem, thanks a lot. I am writing the complete step by step tutorials on Single Page Application http://techfunda.com/Howto/angularjs/single-page-application and I owe something to you for this help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the .Get() method of the service in your controller.

```
$scope.GetMyData = PDService.Get().then(function (d) {        
        $scope.PersonalDetails = d;
});
```

This line assigns the result of your .Get() method to the variable $scope.GetMyData.

Instead, try:

```
$scope.GetMyData = PDService.Get;
```

Or, better yet, just inject the $http service into your controller and create a get function there. Your service is just a wrapper around $http with a specific URL, which could be stored as a constant instead.

```
$scope.getMyData = function() {
     $http.get('/api/PersonalDetails')
         .then(handleSuccess, handleError);
};
```